# Remove trailing zeros from NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I have an NSData with an arbitrary amount of 0's trailing. I can never be certain of the amount of 0's that are trailing.

How can I trim my NSData object so that only the trailing 0's are removed?

Comment: By "trailing zeros" do you mean you want to remove bytes with a value of `0` from the end of the data?

Comment: Yes I do mean that - sorry, should have specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the underlying data as `const void *` by calling `bytes` on your `NSData` object, then walk through the bytes backwards until you find a non-zero byte. Then you could create a new `NSData` of the new, shorter length by calling `subdataWithRange:` on your original `NSData`.